# Posting a jaiku using xcode

Tags: iphone, post, httprequest

```
NSMutableURLRequest *jaikuRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.jaiku.com/json"]
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                                           timeoutInterval:60.0];



[jaikuRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
NSString *jbody= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"method=presence.send&user=XXusernameXX&personal_key=XXpersonalkeyXX&message=%@", 
encodedMsg];

[jaikuRequest setHTTPBody:[[NSString stringWithFormat:jbody] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
```

I wrote the above code snippet to be able to post a jaiku on jaiku.com. I've come across similar samples in other languages for posting a jaiku. However i get the following response in the console:

```
{"status": "error", "message": "Invalid API user", "code": 0}
```

what could be the error or if im wrong, what is the correct approach to posting a jaiku using xcode?

Comment: That error message makes it sound like the username/password are wrong.

Comment: interestingly, the api is said to require only the username & personalkey, both of which i have verified to be correct. despite that i get the response as shown.

Comment: Some samples that jaiku:
http://blog.modsaid.com/2008/05/posting-messages-using-jaiku-api.html
&
http://danhounshell.com/blogs/dan/archive/2007/10/16/make-jaiku-presence-updates-programmatically.aspx
Any suggestions hw it can be implemented in xcode?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the legacy authentication which is deprecated and sounds like it might not be fully functional any longer (certainly untested):

http://www.jaiku.com/api/docs/authentication

You should try using the new OAuth authentication they document at the above link.  definitely more complicated (and secure).